# Qt readAllStandardOutput() causes unexpected program end

Tags: qt, qt4

When I try to emit readAllStandardOutput() to a QString im getting an unexpected program crash, even if i connvert the QByteStream to a QString, any idea why that is? heres teh source

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QString>


#include "exeprocess.h"

/*main window ---------------------------------------*/

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QProcess *proc;

signals:
    void outLog(QString outLogVar); //plug this into the QTextEdit box

public slots:
    void logReady(); // plug the QProcess into this


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};




#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QByteArray>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QProcess *proc = new QProcess; //initialize proc
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "-h";

    connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput ()), this, SLOT(logReady()));

    proc->start("/Applications/Graphics/3Delight-9.0.87/bin/renderdl", arguments);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::logReady(){
    QString str = proc->readAllStandardOutput();
    emit outLog(str);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
QProcess *proc = new QProcess; //initialize proc
```

You're shadowing the member variable by reusing that name. When logReady is called, the 'proc' that you call readAllStandardOutput() on is a different (null) pointer and so everything crashes. The fix is simple: replace the above line with

```
proc = new QProcess;
```

Comment: that works a dream but i have no idea why, what do you mean by shadowed? thanks PAG, j

Comment: @jonathan When you declare the local `proc` variable, it just hides the decalration of the class member variable, so that all uses of `proc` in the method refer to the local one, which is not the member variable. If you have at least the smallest knowledge of C++, you should see the error, know that it's pointed out.

Comment: It could also be a good idea, to make the main window a parent of the process by using `new QProcess(this)`, so that it get's deleted automatically when the main window get's destroyed.

Comment: @Christian Rau, I'm totally new to this hence the silly errors, but im getting there, with the right help:) thanks for the quick reply.